# CountIf acting strange on a lot of data[Excel 2007]

Tags: excel, count, countif

I have a two column set of data, I'm trying to find how many times each value repeats using count.if(). Problem is that my two columns are 783361 rows long, and after like 10 minutes of the loading circle thingy goes away, only the first entries look accurate, however, most of the other data shows the same count, which seemed wrong at first. I then clicked on the formula to see if it didn't drag correctly, turned out it was, and I hit enter. Instantly the count updated to a value that seemed more accurate, I tried this again on random rows, and the same happened. I *could* go one by one, but again, it's 783361 entries.

Any idea on how to make the evaluations... correct?

If you need any further information I'll happily provide it :^)

Comment: Can you check you have 'Automatic' calculation enabled? On the ribbon at the top, select 'Formulas', on the far right 'Calculation Options' and then select 'Automatic'.

Comment: Yeah, it is enabled :/

Comment: Try converting your spreadsheet to *.xslb format to see if it helps.

Comment: I couldn't try it at school, but if you see below I "figured" how to make it work in another computer, but I'm not certain what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently almost a million entries to process was too much for my uni's computers, the calculation time would time out somehow and just defalut every cell it hadn't evaluated to the last calculated value.

I figure this is the case because when I got home I tried again and it froze processing for solid 30 minutes and every entry I checked seemed correct. My home computer is an i7 8RAM vs i3 4RAM, so I guess that helps too.

I guess now the question turns into "How to increase calculation time limits in excel?"

Anyways, thanks for the interest everyone, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If disabled, try enabling Automatic calculations:

Excel 2007:

```
Office button > Excel options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation > Automatic.
```

If that does not work, you can try to disable it, close Excel, then open and re-enable it, though that is not likely to work either (worth a shot).

Beyond that, you may want to try reinstalling based on the post I found on Super User by the title of [Excel 2007 won't auto-calculate](https://superuser.com/a/109364/443938)

Please report back and let me know if either of these help.